# How can we detect memory leaks in a COM Interop application?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, com-interop

WHat would be the best way to detect memory management issues with a C# winform app that uses COM interop. A COM assembly is referenced and its methods are used for many calculations and transactions.

Is there any tool that can identify the objects[interop] which are loaded in memory but not unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

The RCW for a COM component is just a managed class.  Any half-decent .NET memory profiler will show you any that staying referenced unintentionally.  If the COM server itself is leaking then you'll need one that can track unmanaged memory.  That invariably requires having the source code for the server so you can figure out exactly what is leaked.  And to actually do something about it.

There are already a gazillion questions about .NET memory profilers.  Type ".NET memory profiler" in the search box at the upper right.

Answer (score 0):

Try AQTime profiler ,im playing with it for some time and it has nice profilers for unmanaged (com)and managed application,you can download thw demo from here:
http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/performance-profiling/sign-up/